# setAdapter from ListView acts like addView instead than just adding text on the View

Tags: java, android, listview, view, addition

my name is Francesco and I was trying to create a chat-app, just to see how much time I would spend doing it.
Unluckily there's a thing that seems like a bug for me, but maybe I'm wrong.

I've 3 classes:

1. A Global class to share variables.
2. A FriendList class.
3. A ChatRoom class.

The "buggy" piece of code is into the ChatRoom class. It works really fine into the FriendList class, it just uses the method setAdapter from the ListView but when it has to use it, instead of adding text to the ListView, it adds 2 views(an autoCompleteTextView and a Button), that are the 2 views I'm using in the ChatRoom class to write and send messages...

The layout of the ChatRoom is the same of the FriendList with the difference that in the ChatRoom one there is an autoCompleteTextView, a Button to send messages and 2 TextViews instead of one, cause I wanted to put the different messages to the right or left depending on who wrote the message.

piece of the FriendList code:

```
friendList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);

list = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(currentActivity, R.layout.friendlist_layout, R.id.textview, list);
friendList.setAdapter(adapter);

adapter.add("francesco");
adapter.add("funkyserver");

friendList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

piece of ChatRoom code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            String messageToSend = messageInput.getText().toString();
            if (messageToSend != "" | messageToSend != null) {
                            chat.sendMessage(messageInput.getText().toString());
                    messageListAdapterR.add(messageToSend);
                    messageListAdapterL.add("");
                    currentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                messageListView.setAdapter(messageListAdapterL);
                                messageListView.setAdapter(messageListAdapterR);
                        }
                    });
            }

       ...
```

p.s. Both the codes are into a runOnUiThread.

Thanks in advance for the replies :)

Comment: You don't have to setAdapter every time when you click and Do you know that you set adapter two times?

Comment: I call the method setAdapter 2 times cause they are 2 different TextViews, anyway I want to add the message only when the user clicks on the "send button"

Comment: I am talking about these lines messageListView.setAdapter(messageListAdapterL);
messageListView.setAdapter(messageListAdapterR);

Comment: Basically you do many thinks wrong in your code. Do you now how to add new  item to adapter? Do you know that onClick action is done on UI thread?

Comment: Me too... if you see the ListAdapters are 2 different ListAdapters, one of them uses the LeftTextView(that aligns messages to the Left) and the other one uses the RightTextView(that aligns messages to the Right).

Comment: Anyway that's not the problem...
The point is, that when I click the button it add 2 views on instead than add text on the already present ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you modify the data attached to the adapter bound to a `ListView`, you do not call `setAdapter()` again to update the view. That is what `notifyDataSetChanged()` is for.  Your first pseudo-code sample ought to look something more like this:

```
friendList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);

list = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(currentActivity,
        R.layout.friendlist_layout, R.id.textview, list);
friendList.setAdapter(adapter);

adapter.add("francesco");
adapter.add("funkyserver");

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

*Actually, to be even more precise, even `notifyDataSetChanged()` shouldn't be necessary when adding items to the adapter directly…it should call that method internally.*

With regards to your second example, `ListView` cannot display data from multiple adapters. When your code calls:

```
messageListView.setAdapter(messageListAdapterL);
messageListView.setAdapter(messageListAdapterR);
```

The second method call ***overrides*** the first and all you will see are items from `messageListAdapterR`. If you want the data from both "lists" to show in the view, they have to be combined into a single adapter.

Comment: Oh ok thank you very much, I didn't know about the notifyDataSetChanged() method and I didn't understand why I had to combined them into a single adapter.

Can't I use 2 TextViews into a single adapter? Cause I wanted to put certain messages to the left and others to the right.

Comment: Yes, this is what view types are for. Your single adapter can own two lists of "messages", declare that is supports two view types, and return views for the "left" and "right" type. Have a look at `getItemViewType()` in the adapter class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int) . You also have to override `getViewTypeCount()` so that adapter knows how many types you want to use.

Comment: I'm new with ArrayLists and ListAdapters :/ This is one of the 2 adapters I put:

messageListAdapterL = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.chatroom_layout, R.id.leftTextView, messageList);

So, I should use another constructor that can specify both the textviews I want to use?

Comment: Just to let you know, I'm using ArrayAdapter and not ListAdapter :/

Comment: ArrayAdapter is a ListAdapter :) ...and you won't get any of that custom functionality without building your own adapter implementation. Not terribly difficult, here's one of many tutorials on the matter: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown

Comment: Thank you a lot Devunwired, I did it, it seems like I still need 2 TextViews, I'll figure it out myself anyway :) I didn't know about the ListActivity too .o.

Comment: If this answer was helpful to you, please feel free to upvote or accept it.